# Changing css on click for one of many duplicate divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So i have a div.

```
<div class="class" ng-click="example()"></div>
```

I am using angular 1.6.4 and jQuery. This div has a background color and a border color. I want to change those when i click this div. I know I can do something like this:

```
$scope.example = function(){
    $(".class").addClass("class_change");
};
```

OR

```
$scope.example = function(){
    $(".class").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".class").css("border-color", "red");
};
```

My question arises when I have copies of that div on the same page, and I only want it to change the div I click, not all of them.

```
<div class="class" ng-click="example()"></div>
<div class="class" ng-click="example()"></div>
<div class="class" ng-click="example()"></div>
<div class="class" ng-click="example()"></div>
```

I had assumed I could use $(this), but for some reason it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend avoiding using jQuery with Angular. If you absolutely have to use jQuery, the controller is not the place to be doing DOM manipulation - that should be in a directive.

Comment: *"$(this)..not working"* Not sure how it works with `ng-click`, but have you tried: `ng-click="example(this);"` and `$scope.example = function(el) { $(el)...`  that's how you would do it with javascript and onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From AngularJS [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-):

> Directives like ngClick and ngFocus expose a $event object within the scope of that expression. The object is an instance of a jQuery Event Object when jQuery is present or a similar jqLite object.

You can pass it like

```
<div class="class" ng-click="example($event)"></div>
```

And then you can read [target property](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) in your method like:

```
$scope.example = function($event){
    var target = $($event.target);
    $(target).css("background-color", "white");
    $(target).css("border-color", "red");
};
```

But it is not a good practice to manipulate the DOM outside of AngularJS context. You can use [`ng-style` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) to set style on elements conditionally and you can write your own directive that can store the state of the element and apply the styles.

Comment: And how would you remove the css? For example, I click the first div, it adds the css, but when i click the second one, i want to remove it from the first?

Comment: Don't use css, use classes.  Then you can `addClass` / `removeClass`  (eg `$(".redonwhite").removeClass("redonwhite");$(target).addClass("redonwhite");`

Comment: You can try `$('.class').each(function(i, obj) { $(obj).css("background-color", "red");  $(obj).css("border-color", "white"); });` before setting styles to the target div element. But it is better to manipulate classes not single css props.

Answer (score 0):

try to add id to your divs to get something like this :

```
<div class="class" id="myDiv-1" ng-click="example('myDiv-1')"></div>
<div class="class" id="myDiv-2" ng-click="example('myDiv-2')"></div>
<div class="class" id="myDiv-3" ng-click="example('myDiv-3')"></div>
<div class="class" id="myDiv-4" ng-click="example('myDiv-4')"></div>
```

then change your function to  :

```
$scope.example = function(myDiv){
    $("#" + myDiv).css("background-color", "white");
    $("#" + myDiv).css("border-color", "red");
};
```